# Is there any online xaml editor like Codepen, jsfiddle in Xamarin?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am Working on Xamarin Forms for Android IoS.

I want to test my UI display in different phone for which I need to download emulator and then run in visual studio which takes a lot time to run and see the output of the code.

Is there any online website or platform where I could test my code and see the output just like CodePen and JsFiddle?

Comment: Have you tried Visual Studio App Center ? https://appcenter.ms/

Comment: Not yet... But I just want to test before it goes.. Is there any free resource where I can just test my xaml code for UI?